# Cherry-pick with ignore whitespace / line-endings

Tags: linux, git, line-endings

is there a way to tell `git cherry-pick` to use the `renormalize` merge strategy?  I'm not sure the `-X` option is working.

I have a bunch of commits that seem to assume one type of line ending, and I'm trying to apply them to a branch that assumes another.  Not having a good time...

Comment: think I may have answered my own question.  `-X renormalize` is not working, but `-X ignore-all-space` is doing the job...

Answer (score 60, accepted):

So, for completeness, the answer is that the `ignore-all-space` merge strategy does the job:

```
git cherry-pick -X ignore-all-space <commit-id>
```

And that will let you painlessly cherry-pick commits made when the file had, eg, windows line endings onto a version that has unix file endings.

Answer (score 7):

I know this question is significantly old, but adding this answer because this is the first post from googling "git cherry-pick ignore whitespace".

Even though `-X ignore-all-space` works fine, you have to manually check the commit if the cherry-pick without ignore space option had some conflicts. (or use `--no-commit` while cherry-picking and `git diff --staged` to review it)

In some cases, `-X ignore-all-space` option looks fine, but some indentations are wrong.

For example, suppose you had some merge conflict with leading whitespace while not using ignore-all-space, like this:

```
    Change from theirs, Indent level 1(no conflict with/out whitespace)
<<<<< HEAD
Indent level 0
=====
    Indent level 1 without any code change
>>>>> cherry-picked commit
```

In this case, `-X ignore-all-space` shows no conflict but the actual commit will look like this:

```
    Change from theirs, indent level 1
Indent level 0
```

What happened here is they changed logic so the previous code (Indent level 0) should be indented to level 1, but it didn't because you specified ignore-**all**-space option.

So the tl;dr is:

1. `-X ignore-all-space` option also ignores leading whitespaces, which might be troublesome in some situations and languages like Python.
2. So you have to manually review after using that option, or...
3. Use `-X ignore-space-at-eol` instead, and handle leading whitespace conflicts manually.

But don't stop reading, because these options are not the main reason of this problems - the core of this problem is not everyone is sticking to same whitespace rules.

For leading&trailing whitespaces: use linting tools, or IDEs, or whatever to stick to same rules. This is not OS-specific and can be followed if your team puts some effort to making other developers' life easier.

For eol changes: this is OS-specific, but git fortunately supports core.autocrlf and core.eol for multi-platform development enveronment. see [git-scm](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration) for more details.

Comment: [`ignore-cr-at-eol`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#Documentation/git-merge.txt-ignore-cr-at-eol) strategy comes to be useful in my case as well. I.e. `-X ignore-cr-at-eol`. ([Additional explanation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt---ignore-cr-at-eol)).